# Can we access social media advertisements and information like how many likes, comments, shares they received using their APIs?

Tags: dataset, social-network-analysis

I want to access social media advertisements and information about how popular they were ( how many likes, comments and shares they received and the comments). Can I get these information using [these APIs](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/422/publicly-available-social-network-datasets-apis?newreg=eeb7ba99c0844fd2969a7f49da720bcb) ? Or else where can I get this data?