# multi channel feature classification using deep feed forward neural network on tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, deep-learning, dataset

Can any one suggest a dataset that contains multi channel/multi dimensional feature values that can be classified using a deep feed forward neural network?

Please ask me if the question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified which deep net you are using. You can use any data set which is of the right format in `TensorFlow`. If you are using convolutional networks, You may need data which locality is important. In this case:

- MNIST data set
- ImageNet data set

may help you. If you are doing other tasks I highly recommend you taking a look at [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/155/28175) question which is so much popular and has great answers.

If I want to quote, I quote the [following answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/4997/28175). [Network Repository](http://networkrepository.com) an interactive data repository with over 600+ networks in 20+ collections; from large-scale social networks, web graphs, biological networks, communication and technological networks my **help** you.

> ### Data Sets
>
> - [Academic Torrents](http://academictorrents.com/)
> - [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public)
> - [hadoopilluminated.com](http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_illuminated/Public_Bigdata_Sets.html)
> - [data.gov](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset)
> - [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com/)
> - [freebase.com](https://www.freebase.com/)
> - [usgovxml.com](http://usgovxml.com/)
> - [enigma.com](http://public.enigma.com/)
> - [datahub.io](http://datahub.io/)
> - [aws.amazon.com/datasets](http://aws.amazon.com/datasets)
> - [databib.org](http://databib.org/)
> - [datacite.org](http://www.datacite.org)
> - [quandl.com](https://www.quandl.com/)
> - [figshare.com](http://figshare.com/)
> - [GeoLite Legacy Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)
> - [Quora's Big Datasets Answer](http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public)
> - [Public Big Data Sets](http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_illuminated/Public_Bigdata_Sets.html)
> - [Houston Data Portal](http://data.ohouston.org/)
> - [Kaggle Data Sources](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/DataSources)
> - [A Deep Catalog of Human Genetic Variation](http://www.1000genomes.org/data)
> - [A community-curated database of well-known people, places, and things](https://www.freebase.com/)
> - [Google Public Data](http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory)
> - [World Bank Data](http://data.worldbank.org/)
> - [NYC Taxi data](http://nyctaxi.herokuapp.com/)
> - [Open Data Philly](http://www.opendataphilly.org/) Connecting people with data for Philadelphia
> - [Network Repository](http://networkrepository.com) An interactive data repository with over 600+ networks  in 20+ collections; from large-scale social networks, web graphs, biological networks, communication and technological networks, etc.
> - [A list of useful sources](http://ahmetkurnaz.net/en/statistical-data-sources/) A blog post includes many data set databases

[Data Sets](https://github.com/okulbilisim/awesome-datascience#data-sets) From [awesome-datascience](https://github.com/okulbilisim/awesome-datascience)