# Is there a dataset with news articles and their headlines?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, machine-translation, automatic-summarization

I need a set of news headlines and articles to help me in a project on automatic summarization. Is there such a dataset or something similar?

Comment: This is better suited for https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/155/28175).

Comment: There's one with Medium.com Blog posts!

Answer (score 2):

The most widely used ones in text summarization research is the [DUC](https://duc.nist.gov/data.html) dataset. If you see a paper using dataset "DUC 2015" or "DUC 2016" that's from here.

I have also personally used the [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/resources/archive/us/) arcihve. You just need to download each article with `wget` or something similar. See also [here](https://github.com/philipperemy/Reuters-full-data-set).

The [CNN / DailyMail](https://cs.nyu.edu/~kcho/DMQA/) dataset is also widely used in summarization especially in recent years, although it labels itself as a Q&A dataset.

Comment: How can you log in to get the DUC dataset? I can't figure out how I can register with my institution's email.

Comment: The link in the answer has instructions about how to request access to the dataset. Why not read it?