# Publicly available news APIs/datasets?

Tags: dataset, open-source, crawling

In addition to our list of [publicly available datasets](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/155/publicly-available-datasets), I'd like to know if there is any list of publicly available news datasets/crawling APIs. It would be very nice if alongside with a link to the dataset/API, characteristics of the data available were added. Such information should be, and is not limited to:

- the name of the news network / news aggregator;
- what kind of news information it provides (title, snippet, full-article, date, author, url, ...);
- whether it allows for crawling its contents via an API (and rate: 10/min, 1k/month, ...);
- whether it simply provides a snapshot of the whole dataset.
- news sources covered
- date range of news content coverage

Any suggestions and further characteristics to be added are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There is [GoogleNews](https://pypi.org/project/GoogleNews/) package for Python. It allows queries by data range, keyword, and language.

Comment: Looking forward to trying this!